# Some web pages won't download fully

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking

Some web pages won't download fully under any browser on any computer connected to the network. I have Internet access through a wireless modem/router (2 Mbps DSL connection, wireless reception is excellent). I use Opera and when I turn on Opera turbo the same sites download fully. I tried changing to some other dns (opendns, google dns), but it made no difference. What would you suggest I try?

OS : Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Give us example.  What DNS are you using?

Comment: My dns is my ISP's dns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Opera Website](http://help.opera.com/Linux/11.10/en/turbo.html) (bold is mine):

> "The technology behind Opera Turbo **is a proxy server** with server-side
>   compression of webpages. A compression rate of up to 80% can be
>   achieved, in part by reducing the quality of images.

My guess is that your provider is having issues reaching some of the content servers you are pointing to. The "compressing proxy server" your browser is pointing to when you are using "Opera Turbo" is not among those. So, your provider - faulty to get somewhere on the net - reaches successfully the Opera Turbo server, which in turn gets all the pages from wherever you want and gives them back to you; so you're able to reach all of the net from that source.

To verify if this guess is correct I would try to use the Tor browser: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

If **that** can leave the Internet and get you everywhere, too (although at a way slower rate than with Opera) that would confirm this. The only thing you could do then would be give a call to your ISP.

Also, *theorethically* you could have some kind of firewall that is preventing *you* to leave the Internet towards certain sites (not the Opera Turbo proxy, see above), but that is less likely.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. All pages download fully with Tor browser. I don't use any kind of software firewall other than built in (windows firewall). So you think that means there is a problem with my ISP? Why is it though that just some parts of some web pages don't download?

Comment: When you use the other DNS, have you verified it's actually used? Some ISP override DNS request to their own DNS, which may be broken or intentionally blocking some URL. Check http://www.opendns.com/welcome/oops/ for OpenDNS, or http://setup.nortondns.com/ for Norton DNS (I can't find any test URL for Google DNS)

Comment: You were right. I didn't even bother to look which DNS I was using. I guess my ISP was overriding my DNS request to their own. Thank you. I will try to contact them.